# How to add a literal quote in Laravel's .env file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to add a string value to my `.env` file that contains quotes like so.

`APP_NAME="Hacking"`

Laravel assumes the quotes are being used to define the string, but I want the literal quote in the string.

I've also tried the following.

```
APP_NAME='"Hacking"'

APP_NAME=\"Hacking\"

APP_NAME="\"Hacking\""
```

Comment: What happens to your third option? And why would you want a string in your app name?

Comment: It omits the quotes from the output. I used APP_NAME as an example, but I wanted each page's title to contain a string in quotes.

Comment: I thought this might help someone, since it's somewhat related to this subject, there is an update on the behavior of env() method in Laravel >= 5.8, please checkout the following link to Laravel's upgrade manuals: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#environment-variable-parsing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
APP_NAME='""Hacking""'
```

or this:

```
APP_NAME="\"\"Hacking\"\""
```

---

The dotenv library removes the outer layer of single or double quotes when it sets the environment variable:
https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/fa1a24d/src/Loader.php#L249

Laravel's `env()` helper removes the outer layer of double quotes when it retrieves the variable:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2ab2fc6/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L613

Comment: Thanks for the reply. save me time